# Can lead() return the next row only when a condition is met?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Recently my company upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to 2016, so I want to take advantage of some "new" features, one of which is `lead()`.

I understand the basic usage, but I want to know if I can return the next row only when a condition is met. My original query looked like the following, where `x.next_id is null` if the next row isn't more than 12 days past the current row.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.date_a, 
    x.next_id
FROM 
    table a
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         next_id = i.intIndex
     FROM 
         table i
     WHERE 
         i.date_a > DATEADD(DAY, 12, a.date_a)
     ORDER BY
         date_a, id ASC) x
ORDER BY
    date_a, id ASC
```

Data might look like the following, where the third column is added by the query:

```
id        date_a       next_id
--------------------------------
1798678   2014-12-01   NULL
1798689   2013-01-05   1798688
1798688   2014-03-31   NULL
1798696   2013-04-03   1798694
1798694   2013-08-12   1798691
1798691   2014-09-30   NULL
1798698   2013-05-14   1798697
1798697   2013-08-29   NULL
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: I'm not sure `LEAD` will help you here, for example, if you had 3 rows on consecutive dates, and than a 4th that is 20 days later, all the prior rows would need to show the date for 20 days later. That isn't how `LEAD` works,

Comment: If I run your query on your data set, I'm getting a different result for your data set. Can you provide a clear and correct data set please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this data set (your result table; minus the result column):

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(id INT PRIMARY KEY,date_a DATE);
INSERT INTO some_table(id,date_a)
VALUES (1798678,'2014-12-01'),
(1798689,'2013-01-05'),
(1798688,'2014-03-31'),
(1798696,'2013-04-03'),
(1798694,'2013-08-12'),
(1798691,'2014-09-30'),
(1798698,'2013-05-14'),
(1798697,'2013-08-29');
```

This [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57766/8) returns the same result set as what the query you have returns:

```
SELECT
    id,
    date_a,
    next_id=
        CASE WHEN LEAD(date_a) OVER (ORDER BY date_a,id)>DATEADD(DAY,12,date_a)
            THEN LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY date_a,id)
            ELSE NULL
        END
FROM
    some_table
ORDER BY
    date_a,id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does give me the same results. And the performance in the few tests I did so far has an impressive boost.